# How would a completely dynamic (every page dynamically generated) web site remain search engine-friendly?

Tags: php, search, web-applications, search-engine, structure

Most completely dynamic web sites allow nearly every page to be found, crawled and indexed by search engines. How would this be properly implemented to allow a completely dynamic web site to be search engine-friendly? Note that there is no directory structure, users can type in complex URLs (`www.example.com/news/recent`) but the folder structure doesn't actually exist, it is all handled by htaccess, which submits the url entered to the main web application for page generation.

Answer (score 2):

Search engines access websites nearly the same way as a visitor.  If the search engine web crawler gets to www.example.com/news/recent, it will index the results which will then be search-able.

Most websites have static links to point to content, so the top news article might be on www.example.com/news/recent, but it could also be on www.example.com/news/9234.  That gives search engines somewhere permanent to link to.  The search engine doesn't care if www.example.com/news/9234 really loads www.example.com/pages/newsitems.php?item=9234, that's all hidden.

Another handy way is through [site maps](http://www.sitemaps.org/), which provide the search engine a direct list/map of pages on the website that can be more complicated/less pretty.

Comment: SEF URLs, Permalinks, and site maps about sum it up on the technical side. I'd just like to add that for search engines, as well as people, content is king.